# get unique values from dictionary<string, Ilist<Object>> C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has data of the form

```
key ,  value
1   ,  1 0 1
       1 1 1

2   , 1 2 3
      4 5 6

3   , 1 0 1
      1 1 1 

 and so on.
```

I want to get the unique value of the IList in other dictionary along with the new key.
Can anyone help me how to proceed with this.

Comment: In your example, each list is unique, what do you mean? From where should the new key be produced?

Comment: If you show the anticipated output we might be able to help.

Comment: Since further edits don't seem to be forthcoming I'm going to have to vote against your question until you improve it. If you make it less ambiguous I'll happily reverse my actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a nicer way to do it, than this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IList<int>>();

var uniques = new Dictionary<string, IList<int>>();

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    if(!uniques.Any(val => val.Value.SequenceEqual(kvp.Value)))
        uniques.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: if you enumerate a generic Dictionary it yields a sequnece of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` so `list` is a misleading variable name to represent that type, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Dave, this seems to be working perfectly fine for my case.

Answer (score 0):

How about treating your value as HashSet instead of IList. Then you will be able to group your dictionary by value using equality comparer CreateSetComparer.

```
  var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IList<Object>>
                    {
                        {"1", new List<object> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
                        {"2", new List<object> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}},
                        {"3", new List<object> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
                    };
    var dictionaryHashSets = dictionary.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, v=> new HashSet<Object>(v.Value));
    var reverseDictionary = dictionaryHashSets.GroupBy(pair => pair.Value, HashSet<Object>.CreateSetComparer()).ToDictionary(gk => gk.Key, gv => gv.Select(pair => pair.Key));
```